# Pass variables into rails partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

So basically in my partial I have the following line of code

```
...
<%= " active" if current_user."#{prop_row}" == "repeat-x" %>
...
```

So I tried to pass in the following variables "prop_id", "prop_row" using:

```
<%= render :partial => "users/image_props/repeat", :prop_id => "mbr", :prop_row => "main_background_repeat" %>
```

I get the error

```
/Users/codyjames408/rails/moz/app/views/users/image_props/_repeat.html.erb:4: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG
...= ( " active" if current_user."#{prop_row}" == "repeat-x" );...
...     

                      ^
```

I think the errors because its appending a string instead of the row method. But I am pulling my hair trying to figure how to work around this.

I would love to turn this into a big helper method or something! I just don't know how...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If prop_row is a string, containing the name of an attribute, you ucan do this:

```
<%= " active" if current_user.attributes[prop_row] == "repeat-x" %>
```

Or use this:

```
<%= " active" if current_user.send(prop_row.to_sym) == "repeat-x" %>
```